# Django get model id within __init__

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
class PreEncounterAttendanceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PreEncounterAttendance
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PreEncounterAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        this_class = self.instance.pre_encounter_class.id
        visitors = Visitor.objects.exclude(id__in=PreEncounterAttendance.objects.all().exclude(pre_encounter_class__id=this_class).values_list('student', flat=True))
        self.fields['student'].queryset = visitors
```

It works when I enter the number manually, but when I use `self.instance.pre_encounter_class.id` it fails because it is a `NoneType`.

Is there another way to do this?

**EDIT:**
Found the issue. I had to check if the instance id existed first:

```
class PreEncounterAttendanceForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = PreEncounterAttendance
    fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PreEncounterAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.id:
        if self.instance.pre_encounter_class.id:
            this_class = self.instance.pre_encounter_class.id
            visitors = Visitor.objects.exclude(id__in=PreEncounterAttendance.objects.all().exclude(pre_encounter_class__id=this_class).values_list('student', flat=True))
            self.fields['student'].queryset = visitors
    else:
        visitors = Visitor.objects.exclude(id__in=PreEncounterAttendance.objects.all().values_list('student', flat=True))
        self.fields['student'].queryset = visitors
```

Comment: Are you passing model obj `instance` as a keyword argument when creating a form instance?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way can be pass the `class id` in the kwargs from the view, then pop it before call `super()`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    this_class = kwargs.pop('class_id', None)
    super(PreEncounterAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
    visitors = Visitor.objects.exclude(id__in=PreEncounterAttendance.objects.all().exclude(pre_encounter_class__id=this_class).values_list('student', flat=True))
    self.fields['student'].queryset = visitors
```